# AssociationOverrides not works to sub entities in inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a hierarchy of entities, which in the root entity, has a relation that must be read only. But in the leaf entity, this relationship should not have this behavior.

```
@Entity
class X {@Id private Long id;} //gets sets

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
class Root {
    @Id private Long id; //gets sets

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "X_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) //READ ONLY
    private X x;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ExampleValue")
@AssociationOverrides({ //I try to override to becomes no longer read only
    @AssociationOverride(name = "x", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "X_ID", referencedColumnName = "X_ID" nullable = false)}
}
class Leaf extends Root {
}
```

But when i invoke a Entity Manager persist in a Leaf object, the generated sql not contains X_ID column information.

Comment: are you missing to close the brackets correctly on `@ AssociationOverrides `?

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question to demonstrate classes in compiling and valid form.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ExampleValue")
@AssociationOverrides({ //I try to override to becomes no longer read only
    @AssociationOverride(name = "x", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "X_ID", referencedColumnName = "X_ID" nullable = false)}
}
class Leaf extends Root {
}
```

with

```
 @Entity
   @DiscriminatorValue(value = "ExampleValue")
   @Table(name = "LEAF")
   public class Leaf
   {
    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "x", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "X_ID" nullable = false)})
private Root root;       
}
```

Comment: this seems like the solution but unfortunately it did not work... :( (I edited the question to add this)

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano you edit question in that you have but both name and referencedColumnName  do this use @Embedded@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "x", joinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "X_ID", nullable = false))
})

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano i have edit my aswer and for refernce you can follow this link https://saifulhq.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/hibernate-sample-associationoverrides-attributeoverrides-embeddable-embedded/

Comment: I believe that Embedded isn`t my case. In the link, it`s use for a non entity class. And in my case, i need to override a Entity.